# MediaElement stopped working in XP with Flash 12 in IE8

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I have gotten multiple reports from our XP users (too many of them!) that the player has stopped working (playing MP3's) on our website.  I have an XP VM that I fired up for testing and sure enough, when running Flash 12 on IE8 on XP, the MediaElement player stopped working.

If I disable the Abode Shockwave plugin, the player does work and I assume that it's using the SilverLight plugin because if I disable that plugin, I am prompted to download the MP3 file and Windows Media Player plays the file.  So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a workaround or fix for the Flash 12 problem? (not sure what it is but it is definitely broken).
2. Is there any way to have the player fall back to Windows Media Player without having to download the file?

We have users that are really, really non-technical (yeah, running XP and IE8 would be a good indication of that) so I want to make the whole process as uncomplicated as possible.

We might be able to walk them though a simple disabling of Flash but if they don't have Silverlight installed, then all they will see is the "download" link.

If we could either fix the Flash issue or have the player fallback to Windows Media Player (if such a thing is possible) then we might be able to drag these users along for a few more months.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the player to its latest version? (`2.13.2`, as of now) Recently it stopped working for a flash update, but they released a fix for that.

Source: [Internet explorer 6,7,8 with flash player 12 failing #1078](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1078).

Edit: you could try to enable in IE8 just Silverlight. Something like this:

```
var options = {}; // you could insert here default options for every browser

// if IE8
/*@cc_on
  @if (@_jscript_version == 5.8)
    options.mode = 'shim';
    options.plugins = ['silverlight'];
  @end
@*/

$('audio').mediaelementplayer(options);
```

I didn't try, but I think that it would prompt the user to download the plugin, if not present.

Comment: Yes.  I just verified the version is the latest and that there is only one version installed.  It DID work at Flash 11.9.9.0 but as soon as it updated to 12.0.0.77 it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with. By setting .me-plugin to have a css attribute of 'position:static' ended up showing my video.